# ListBox is rendered with disabled attribute in Developer tools in IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two `RadioButton`, one is "dont share" and Other for "Share".
When we Select Share `Radiobutton` , below there is one `listbox` with `id ="Available"` which has few members to select multiple or single .
Below that we have buttons (AddAll, RemoveAll, Add, Remove).
Below that, One more List box `id="selected"` where we get all selected items from List Box.
After Upgrading to .Net Framework 4.8, My issue is the `ListBoxs` and Buttons are rendering with disabled Attribute.
Tried many solutions by remove, `enabled=true`, but no luck.

This is the Code of List box from Developer tools,

```
<SELECT disabled id=EditControl_List1_List2_Available class=selectbind multiple size=10 name=EditControl$List1$List2$Available list-type="exclude"> 
    <OPTION value=106>Guest</OPTION>
    <OPTION value=105>User</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=107>NewYork</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=108>JB</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=86>Admins</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=89>PRIVATE</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=95>Public</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=90>Analysis</OPTION> 
    <OPTION value=87>Observation</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

```
if(...) // condition is met, enable one of the ListBoxes and disable the other 
   ListBoxA.Enabled = true; 
   ListBoxB.Enabled = false; 
} else { //Otherwise, do the opposite if the condition wasn't met  
   ListBoxA.Enabled = false; 
   ListBoxB.Enabled = true; 
}
```

Web.config snippet:

```
<system.web> 
   <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" enableViewStateMac="True" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"> </pages> <!-- Other sections --> 
</system.web>
```

Can anyone please help on this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please provide some snippets of your code and html.

Comment: Hello @sachita iyer, I updated your post to include what you post in the comment section. You can update your post to include other info next time. Will check I again if I can help with your problem. Will get back if I found something.

Comment: Can anyone please help on this i am stuck ?